# .htaccess vs .htprotect for redirect..?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What's the difference between `.htaccess` and `.htprotect`, and will `mod_rewrite` 301 redirects work if placed in `.htprotect`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible that your server uses a different name for the [distributed configuration files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/htaccess.html) that’s default name is `.htaccess` (see [`AccessFileName` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#accessfilename)). It’s best you simply ask your provider.